# Weak convergence in the intersection of Lebesgue spaces or Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $B:=B_1\cap B_2\cap...\cap B_n$, where each $B_j$ is a *reflexive* Lebesgue space or Sobolev space (such as $L^4$, $H^1$, etc.) on a domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then $B$ is a Banach space endowed with the norm 
$$\|\cdot\| = \|\cdot\|_{B_1}+...+\|\cdot\|_{B_n}.$$ 
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $B$ and $f\in B$.

> Is the assertion that $f_n$ weakly converges to $f$ in $B$ equivalent to the assertion that $f_n$ weakly converges to $f$ in each $B_j$?

Note that it's easy to show that the weak convergence in 
$B$ implies that in each $B_j$. It's the converse that is not obvious. Does anyone know the answer or some reference for it?

**Remark.** My question is closely related to the following:

> Is the reflexivity of every $B_j$ implies the reflexivity of $B$?

To see this, assume $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in each $B_j$. Then $f_n$ is a bounded sequence in each $B_j$, and hence is bounded in $B$. If we can prove that $B$ is reflexive, then $f_n$ has weakly convergent subsequence in $B$. It's easy to show that every weak convergent subsequence of $f_n$ in $B$ must have weak limit $f$, and hence the sequence $f_n$ itself converges weakly to $f$. Conversely, if for every sequence $f_n$ in $B$, $f_n$ converges weakly in each $B_j$ implies that $f_n$ converges weakly in $B$, then $B$ must be reflexive. I omit the proof of this assertion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "yes".  One way of seeing this is to observe that $B$ embeds isometrically into $B_1 \oplus_1 B_2 \dots \oplus_1 B_n$ via $b \mapsto (b,b,\dots, b)$. Another way is to use the (obvious) fact that a sequence in a Banach space converges weakly to $x$ if and only if for every subsequence $y_k$ there are convex combinations of $y_k$ that converge in norm to $x$.

Comment: WOW, so simple, so smart. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

The answer is not so simple in the case of $H^1$ over a bounded smooth domain.In other words,considering its continuous imbedding
in any of the Lebesgue spaces $L^q$ for $q\in[1,p*]$, $p*=np/(n-p)$ for
$p\in[1,n)$, it is possible to define an incomplete metric on $H^1$ and
what is more, Cauchyness if ever seen for $q<p*$ is transferred to $p*$
as well by Cauchy continuity. For an understanding, you may refer to the well known finite measure theoretic result of A.Villani,
together with an obvious 'uniform gauge condition' on any fixed
$H^1$ bounded sequence, noting $1-n/p + n/p* = 0$.